# Nissan Altima Intermittent Emergency brake warning light

Tags: nissan, handbrake, altima

Every morning when I release the emergency brake, the light on the dashboard stays on.  At times I apply and release as hard as I can and the light goes off.  During the day, there is no issue with the light. I'm guessing there is a loose connection.  If so, where do I go about checking the connection?  If not, what else could be wrong?

Comment: The light can come on if the brake fluid is low or where the front brakes need to be done ... all the fluid is sitting in the calipers, which will refill the reservoir once new brake pads are installed.

Comment: As Paulster2 said, this can happen if your brake fluid is just starting to get low. Mine would come on intermittently...but only when slowing down at stoplights. You can check your car's user manual (or look online) to confirm if your dashboard brake light will come on as a "low fluid" indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first port of call should be your brake fluid reservoir. The emergency brake light will stay on if the brake fluid level is low (which could happen if your brake pads are wearing thin).